# 3D Design file labelling and classification for manufacturing

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I have ~1 million 3D design (.STP and/or .OBJ) files of various parts for medical devices, aerospace, automotive or defense systems. I'd like to label them based on appropriate manufacturing methods that are used to physically make them. Some example methods and labels would be milling, turning, injection molding, cnc machining, etc. After labelling, I'd like to architect a system to produce these labels as inference for a new part that has not been physically made yet.
My team (<5 people) have manufacturing domain expertise and can manually label these parts but I'm looking for a more scalable solution that isn't as time consuming. Crowd sourced methods like Mechanical Turk won't work because annotators do not have the domain knowledge to mark the correct label. Labelling platforms like SageMaker/Azure ML Studio only allow image/text/audio datasets, is there a platform that'll help me setup labelling tasks for 3D designs? Furthermore, how can I find more experts that can help scale this up? It seems to me that the only option is to build my own labelling app as an annotator needs these key features -

1. 3D model visualizer so they can spin the part and view any orientation
2. Draw a bounding box (commonly available in other platforms)
3. Toggle measurements in inches/mm

As for label classification I'm looking at architectures like PointNet since my dataset of meshes can be sampled to point clouds. Are there other methods that would work better or worth exploring? Open to any and all suggestions across this pipeline.

Comment: currently I am setting up an architecture to process .stp files and am looking for promising approaches. What approach do you propose?